# How to render <option value="?"></option> as an error in AngularJS?

Tags: forms, angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-init

I have a select with options. I would like to initialize the select value regarding to the user logged `ng-init="own = credentials.user_id"`.

It works when the `user_id` is equals to the value in the `select`. 
But when it's not equals, the value selected is `"?"`. So there is **no error** whereas it should be.

I would like to not selected this `"?"` and invalidate the form.

Do you have a solution ?

```
<div ng-class="{ 'error-select': myForm.lead.$error.required == true }"><span>Leader</span></div>

<select ng-model="lead" name="lead" ng-options="leader.user_id as leader.user_display_name for leader in leaders" ng-init="lead = credentials.user_id" required></select> 

<div ng-class="{ 'error-select': myForm.own.$error.required == true }"><span>Leader</span></div>

<select ng-model="own" name="own" ng-options="own.user_id as own.user_display_name for own in owns" ng-init="own = credentials.user_id" required></select>
```

OUTPUT : user_id = 4

```
  <select t ng-model="lead" name="lead" ng-options="leader.user_id as leader.user_display_name for leader in leaders" ng-init="lead = credentials.user_id" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required">
   <option value="0">Alexandre</option>
   <option value="1">Antoine</option>
   <option value="2">Zaaza</option>
   <option value="3">toro</option>
   <option value="4"selected="selected">Steffi</option>
  </select>

  <select t ng-model="own" name="own" ng-options="own.user_id as leader.user_display_name for own in owns" ng-init="own = credentials.user_id" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required">
   <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
   <option value="1">Alexandre</option>
   <option value="2">Steffi</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Indeed there will be no error, what kind of error you expect or do you want to show any message in this scenario?

Comment: I would like to invalidate the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requirement is not so trivial and there could be several approaches to it. (I am not really sure the chosen one is the best.)

**TL;DR**
Here is the **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/fDdwe/)**.

---

### What's going on ?

First things first: we need to understand what is actually happening.
A control's validity state (`$valid`/`$invalid`) depends on the `$modelValue` or `$viewValue`. The key-point here is that is does not depend on the elements actual `value` property.

When you try to set the `$modelValue` to something that is not in the `users` array (e.g. 3), i.e. that there is no valid `<option>` element available, then Angular will set `$modelValue` and `$viewValue` to 3, but the `<select>`'s `value` will be either `?` (if you haven't added an empty `<option>` element) or whatever the value of the explicitely added empty `<option>`.

But since tha validation is **not** based on the elements `value` everything seems `$valid` from a `required` standpoint.

---

### A solution

One solution is to create a custom directive that has access to the elements **[`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)** and "hooks" itself to the `$render()` function.
This directive will check if the element's `value` is `?` (which indicates an invalid `$modelValue`) and if so, set the `$modelValue`/`$viewValue` to something actually empty, which will correctly update the validity of the control (i.e. an invalid `$modelValue` will trigger our directive's handler to reset that to something empty and the `required` constaint won't be fulfilled).

Here is the code:

```
app.directive('select', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        priority: 10,
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) { return; }
            var originalRender = ctrl.$render.bind(ctrl);
            ctrl.$render = function () {
                originalRender();
                if ((elem.val() === '?') && !ctrl.$isEmpty(ctrl.$modelValue)) {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(undefined);
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/fDdwe/)**.

---

A few points to note regarding the above implementation:

1. I chose to name my directive `select` so it will be applied to all select elements (alongside the native Angular `select` directive - yes that's possible). If you prefer to apply it to specific controls only, then rename it, restrict it to attributes (`restrict: 'A'`) and add it as an attribute to your elements.
2. Due (or thanks) to `require: '?ngModel'`, the control will be ignored if it is not bound to an `ngModel`.
3. Since our directive augments the `ngModelController.$render()` method, which is defined by the `select` directive (executing at priority 0), we need to force our directive's link function to be executed **after** the `select` directive. Thus, it needs a higher priority, because ***["post-link functions are run in reverse [priority] order."](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object)***.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **ng-required** , then angular will accomplish the task for you.
So, when ng-required is set true for the select, and if no value is set for select then $error.required of that model in the form will be set to true.

```
<select ng-model="lead" name="lead" ng-options="leader.user_id as leader.user_display_name for leader in leaders" ng-init="lead = credentials.user_id" ng-required="true"></select>
```

Please find [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb_satchitanand/3TZ9d/2/) for the same. In the script if you comment the code

```
$scope.credentials=$scope.leaders[0];
```

the error flag will be set and form will be invalid and vice-versa.

Comment: I don't think this answer's the question. `ngRequired` will have the exact same effect as `required` in this situation.

Comment: @ExpertSystem Yes, you are correct I have modified my answer. But with this attribute the form will be invalid when no value is set for select and which i hope solves OP problem.

Comment: I don't think it will solve OP's problem (as stated in their question, the problem arises when binding the model to a value that is not present among `ngOptions`. In any case, you can find a detailed explanation of the problems root and a possible solution in my answer.